# Read/Write to a super simple firebase realtime database and nothing happens (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a super simple demo app to test firebase database. I added database to podfile, downloaded the google plist, set up in AppDelegate, and the database rules is fine, too. Now I have the following code in ViewController.swift, but nothing is printed out and nothing happens in the firebase console as well.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentValue = 0
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var handle: DatabaseHandle!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapReadButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.handle = ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
          print(snapshot)
        })
    }

    @IBAction func didTapWriteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.ref.child("test").setValue(currentValue)
        currentValue += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Only thing weird is that there is a "nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed" error in the xcode console when I run the app, but not sure if it's related to the problem. Also I was able to perform google login with Firebase authentication and get the user profile, so I'm assuming that the basic firebase config in my project is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue only happens on simulator. After a couple of hours of trying I finally tried to run the app on my physical device and it works just as expected. So it might be an Xcode bug or something like that...